# IE8 and "Img that was delivered securely" warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

In my https application I am loading some images. If Img src is not available I will show the default image - I got this js that will do the job for IE also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).error(function() {
      this.src = "/shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif";
    });
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
  });
});
```

It works great with IE10, but with IE8 I have a security warning:

Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

If I click on yes -> I cannot see the missing_img.gif, if I click on no everything is ok.

Can you tell me why am I getting this warning and what can I do to remove it?
I don't want to change the client default IE8 settings.

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6886729/1729885).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you are not delivering that particuar image via https. Any resource that is not delivered by https can potentially be modified or read by an attacker whilst in transit. This will throw errors in some browsers, whilst others (such as Chrome) will 'cross out' your 'https' bit in the url to show that not all elements are secure.

To fix it, make sure that all the resources you deliver are via https. So in this case you might want to force it by doing

```
this.src = "https://mysite.com/shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif";
```

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't automatically using https. Maybe someone else can enlighten you on that one.

Comment: That was my first though, from seeing the warning message, but the image path is relative, so it would use the same protocol as the page itself.  If the page is fetched via https then so should the image be.

Comment: True. I did not consider that. But maybe forcing it to https in this case woul at least give an answer either way. If it still gives a secure content warning, then there is a real problem! I'd be interested to see what other browsers are doing, whether they are allowing it silently or whether they use the right protocol.

Comment: I just tried to put my localhost into the https and I still have the same problem. Maybe its related to apache conf?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your image (because you didn't specify https:// as protocol) gets the http:// protocol..

Since this on your secure site, it'll try to load "http://domain.com/shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif" and that's "not secure content on a secure site"

I think you can fix this by either make the path absolute (include the entire part of it including https://your-domain.com), or use "//" (double slashes) and omit the http(s): part, so it'll take the same protocol as the site (https when the site is secure, http otherwise).

Comment: If it's a relative path it should use the same protocol as the page though.

Comment: I tried both         this.src = "https://myLocalHost/shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif"; and //shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif; and Im getting the same problem.

Comment: And if you tried "//myLocalHost/shared/ts/web/images/missing_img.gif"?